# SQLite: INSERT INTO column inserts at bottom of previous column

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

Most documentation on SQL `INSERT INTO` statements involves inserting values row by row into multiple columns in one statement. My workflow is a little different in that there is no relationship between my table's columns. I'm thus populating each column wholesale: when one is done, I move to the next column to populate that one.

The problem is that I don't know how to control where the second column's `INSERT INTO` goes. It's appending `column2` data to `column1`'s last row. How do I reset the cursor's position to insert at the beginning of `column2`?

*Screenshot of the table output*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L72Vt.jpg

Code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('testDB.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (column1 TEXT, column2 TEXT)')

def getData():
    c.execute('INSERT INTO tableName(column1) VALUES(?)', (data_values,))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO tableName(column2) VALUES(?)', (data_values,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT statement inserts an entire row into the table. Null values will be inserted into any columns not supplied in the insert. This is assuming that the columns not in your insert statement can accept null values. If they are set not to your insert will throw an error.

For example `Insert into Table1(Column1) Values('Value1')` and I`nsert into Table1(Column1) Values('Value2')` will do this as below (------ inidicates just Null/blank values):

**Table1**

```
Column1 Column2

Value1  ------

------  Value2
```

If you want to insert some columns into the existing rows you should use UPDATE statement. In the example above instead of second insert if you use update like below, it will update the same row.

```
update Table1 set Column2 = 'Value2' where Column1 = 'Value1'
```

**Table1**

```
Column1 Column2

Value1  Value2
```